# Select per month

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got the following table:

```
purchases(id, item, user, price, time);
```

The `time` field is a `timestamp`.

I need a query that would return one row per month and that row would contain the sum of `price` for each item in that month.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MONTH(`time`) AS month, SUM(price) AS price
FROM your_table
GROUP BY MONTH(`time`)
```

If you have more than one year's data you may also want to include the year in your group by:

```
SELECT YEAR(`time`) AS year, MONTH(`time`) AS month, SUM(price) AS price
FROM your_table
GROUP BY YEAR(`time`), MONTH(`time`)
```

Answer (score 2):

what about `GROUP BY YEAR(DATE(time)) ASC, MONTH(DATE(time)) ASC`?